# I am unable to install guard gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am just new to ruby on rails i tried to install a few gem which were installed. I added gem 'guard' in my gem file then run the bundle install after that i check bundle info guard then it shows 'guard' not found
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBBlj.png)

I asked chatgpt and watch a few videoes but the problem remain unsolved

Comment: check if this helps - https://github.com/guard/guard/issues/717